# How should I pass a sequence of signal through a finished IIR filter in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, infinite-impulse-response

I am new to IIR filter. Lets say if my input signal is [1 -10 3 6 9], and the sampling frequnecy is $f_{s}=360Hz$, the cutoff frequency is $f_{d}=60Hz$, so the calculated $W_{n}$ is $0.4$. I just use the function $butter()$ to obtain the coefficient. The transfer function of my IIR filter is $H(z)=\frac{0.3661(z+1)}{z-0.2678}$. I just want to know after i obtain the transfer function of my IIR filter, how should I pass the input sequence to my IIR filter in MATLAB to see what the output looks like

Comment: Use the Matlab filter function

Comment: `y = filter(b, a, x);` where `x` is your input signal and `y` is the output signal, `b` is numerator and `a` is denominator.